# KitKat specific- android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_white.xml from drawable resource ID

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701186/exception-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-my), but it didn't work for me. I am using an xml as background and getting exceptiion - `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_white.xml from drawable resource ID`. The app is crashing on launch.

**The weird part is it is working fine on devices running Lollypop. On OS <= KitKat, this issue is reproing.**

XML which is being inflated in fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_white" >
    ....Other views here....
```

list_selector_white.xml

```
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_white" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

gradient_bg_hover

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
  <gradient
      android:startColor="?attr/listViewRow"
      android:centerColor="?attr/listViewRow"
      android:endColor="?attr/listViewRow"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**Logcat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at jsoup.LazyAdapterDoubleList.getView(LazyAdapterDoubleList.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:577)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    ... 50 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_white.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02006a
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3879):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.jav
W/ActivityManager(  589):   Force finishing activity free.programming.programming/.MainActivity
W/ActivityManager(  589): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{655864a8 u0 free.programming.programming/.MainActivity t49 f}
```

Any lead on how to fix it?

**[Edit]**
I suspect using `attr` in drawable is causing issues. Initially, I was using simple `@color/...` and everything was working fine.

Comment: is gradient_bg_hover a color?

Comment: Nope. Its a drawable xml

Comment: where is the drawable? `res/drawable-v21`? :D

Comment: I have put it in plain drawable folder

Comment: ah, yeah I think you're right with the `?attr` references. I had [issues with this before](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/pull/70/files#r25123840). Can you declare color resources for the gradient properties and then as the value for those resources use the theme lookups?  `<gradient android:startColor="@color/my_color"` and `<color name="my_color">?attr/listViewRow</color>`

Comment: Seems like you ended up using color codes to fix the issue. The problem here is I have so many things on stake. So, it would be difficult for me to remove `?attr` references. Any other way to fix it?

Comment: Still crashing with same logs :(

Comment: No I don't think so - it's not resolving `?attr/listViewRow` properly - it expects it to be a hex value or a color resource directly. I just tried by using a color resource and putting the `?attr/listViewRow` in there but same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82012/discussion-between-green-goblin-and-ataulm).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference colour attribute in drawable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994091/how-to-reference-colour-attribute-in-drawable)

Comment: there's a duplicate question with some detailed answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue. I will post answer so that it may help future readers.

The problem is that we can't give attr values to `item` and `gradient`. I got the issue fixed by taking different xml files for colors.

I ended up using different versions of list_selector_white_1 and _2.xml to:

```
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_white_1" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover_1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover_1" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

Similarly, I changed gradient_bg_hover and gradient_bg_white to different versions.

Finally, I created an attribute list_selector with format `integer` and used it in fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/list_selector" >
    ....Other views here....
```

I am waiting for the time when I can support API level >= 21 in my app, in order to remove all these hacks.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me - I was defining a corner radius with ?attr/actionBarSize and it was crashing on pre-Lollipop. I changed it to 56dp and works just fine - in my case it is not super important how many dps that is but if you really need it, it sucks

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.
The problem is that you are using `?attr/` in your drawable.
Replace that with a `@color` or `@drawable` and it should go away.
This does unfortunately mean that you have to bundle a drawable for each of your themes, it is a lot cleaner in lollipop.

Check out [this commit](https://github.com/alphamu/PrayTime-Android/commit/12d2e8480102f73c7740aea064e8cbbb8120d46e) of mine on the project I'm working on, it was to resolve exactly this problem.

You could create a `drawable-v21` folder and put a drawable under it in hopes of a good time when you can support v21+ but I have chosen to go the other route and bundle different color resources (something you can see in the main branch, I have teal and default green colors).

Answer (score 4):

Basically no, it's a [bug that was fixed in Lollipop](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251). The suggestion (until you can `minSdkVersion=21`) is to create a different drawable XML file for each different color you need (and have that as a theme attribute, I assume).

The duplicate question, answers and comments discuss this bug: [How to reference colour attribute in drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994091/how-to-reference-colour-attribute-in-drawable)